# Can you get a stack trace from a binary library crash?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

I use a binary library that crashes quite often. When it does, some times I get assembly code in the debug navigator, other times I get absolutely nothing. Not even a signal. It just quits. Now, the author is asking for a stack trace, which I can't provide to my best of knowledge, as long as I only have the binary version of the library. Not entirely sure I'm right, so I though I should ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send crash reports as is to your library developer. He has the correct dSYM file to symbolicate the crash report (like here: [Symbolicating iPhone App Crash Reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460892/symbolicating-iphone-app-crash-reports))